# Cannot find name 'Handlebars'

Tags: javascript, typescript, handlebars.js

I am trying to use handlebar in Typescript. I am receiving the below error

```
/// <reference path="../../../jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../require.d.ts" />
```

I am not able to sort out how can I refer the handlebar defination file to make it working

```
private populateData(data){
    var base=this;
    var jsData=document.getElementById('header').innerHTML;
    var getdata=document.getElementById('header').innerHTML;
    var compiledData = Handlebars.compile(getdata);
    $('.displayData').html(compiledData(data));
}
```

**Error: dev/include/ts/test.ts(43,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Handlebars'**.

**While including @types/handlebar by**

```
import * as Handlebars from 'handlebars';
```

Getting below error

```
>> handlebars.d.ts(21,31): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>> handlebars.d.ts(23,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
>> handlebars.d.ts(98,40): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

Comment: I installed the types, it works, what versions of typescript and the type module do you use?

Comment: var helpers = require('handlebars-helpers')({
  handlebars: Handlebars
}); Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to top of your script:

```
declare const Handlebars: any;
```